# React JS - I am not able to give console.log in the selected option of 'Select'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a form below that is working almost. I am able to give 'console.log' in all typed fields, but I am not able to give console.log in the selected option of 'Select'. How do I solve this? thanks.

```
//Rest of code omitted

const initialValue = {
  tenants: '',
  options: ''
 
}

 //Rest of code omitted

function onChange(evt) {
    const { name, value } = evt.target
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });     
    console.log({ name, value }) //<-- this console.log is NOT returning anything.
  }



 <Select
   options={contractsOptions}
   onChange={obj => dispatch(selectContract(obj && obj.value ? obj.value : ''))}
   name="tenants"
   id="tenants"
   className="select-group"
   isSearchable={true}
   placeholder={<div>Tenants</div>}
   isClearable={true}
   theme={headerSelectTheme}


 />
```

Comment: Ur not passing onChange callback anywhere in Select component.
onChange={obj => onChange()}

Comment: You're not calling that `onChange` function anywhere. The `onChange` prop on your select component just dispatches some action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are not calling the `onChange` function. Secondly if you only want to `console.log` on change of `select` tag you can always do this.

```
<Select
   options={contractsOptions}
   onChange={obj => {dispatch(selectContract(obj && obj.value ? obj.value : ''))};
   console.log("obj",obj);}
   name="tenants"
   id="tenants"
   className="select-group"
   isSearchable={true}
   placeholder={<div>Tenants</div>}
   isClearable={true}
   theme={headerSelectTheme}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

you're not running the on Change function...

```
   <Select
   options={contractsOptions}
   onChange={()=>onChange()}
   name="tenants"
   id="tenants"
   className="select-group"
   isSearchable={true}
   placeholder={<div>Tenants</div>}
   isClearable={true}
   theme={headerSelectTheme}


 />
```

Comment: This will not push the event/value through from the `onChange` triggered by the component.

Comment: yes, of course he needs to add event.target.value like this : ({target})=>onChange(target.value)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `onChange` function is not bound to the `<Select />` component.

Have you tried something like

```js
//Rest of code omitted

const initialValue = {
  tenants: '',
  options: ''
 
}

 //Rest of code omitted

function onChange(evt) {
    console.log(evt);   // I'm adding this before the other ones because I'm not sure what your Select component is returning for onChange event.
    const { name, value } = evt.target
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });   
    console.log({ name, value }) //<-- this console.log is NOT returning anything.
  }



 <Select
   options={contractsOptions}
   onChange={onChange} // here goes the change handling function
   name="tenants"
   id="tenants"
   className="select-group"
   isSearchable={true}
   placeholder={<div>Tenants</div>}
   isClearable={true}
   theme={headerSelectTheme}
 />
```